# Why does a relay open gradually when driven by 555 through an emitter follower?

Tags: relay, 555, emitter-follower

[image: 555 circuit diagram]

A follow-up to my earlier post [Why is the output from this astable 555 the reverse of it's simulation?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/69685/why-is-the-output-from-this-astable-555-the-reverse-of-its-simulation)

The 555 output drives a 2N2222. The 2222 emitter-follower with a 4.7 kΩ resistance to ground, in it's turn, attempts to drive a PCB mountable relay (I meant to drive a 3055 and then the relay but decided to try to drive the relay directly before including the 3055). To determine whether the relay is triggered an analogue multimeter (resistance) has it's leads applied to the contacts on the relay.

This is curiosity rather than a problem; when the 555 output goes high the relay makes a lot of noise, and the NC opens over around 10 seconds from 0 Ω resistance to around 1 kΩ slowing as it increases (some kind of logarithmic rise).

- V<sub>CC</sub> = 12 V
- R<sub>b</sub> at 2N2222 = 330 Ω
- R<sub>e</sub> at 2N2222 = 4.7 kΩ

EDIT: *The [relay JQC-3FC](http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/157071/DBLECTRO/JQC-3FC.html) is connected at the take-off above R3 with the other end of the relay going to ground.*

Applying 12 V to the relay directly switches the contacts instantaneously. Why the gradual opening through the timer circuit?

Comment: Exactly **where** is the relay coil connected? Across the 4k7, between the collector and +12V

Comment: @JImDearden: At the top of the 4k7 with the other end going to ground.

Comment: what is the current rating for the relay coil?

Comment: Circuit please.... at the moment I envision a coil in series with a 4k7.... this is not normal practice.

Comment: Way too much handwaving.  This needs to be closed until a proper schematic is supplied.

Comment: This schematic is better, but it's still not the whole thing. Where's the relay? Where's the "analogue multimeter (resistance) has it's leads applied to the contacts"?

Comment: @PhilFrost: Couldn't figure out do a relay in LTSpice. Same for multimeter...

Comment: @Everyone a relay is a coil next to a switch, maybe with a box drawn around them.

Comment: I know the pictorial representation (+: The component isn't in the library.

Comment: @Everyone Please consider using the (admittedly rather limited) schematic tool CircuitLab that is integrated into this site: Simply press Control-M or click the "Schematic" icon in the little toolbar shown while editing your post. For components not provided in your schematic editor (LTSpice, CircuitLab, or other), common practice is to use the closest appropriate schematic components, and surround them with a box or other indicator to show they are one device. A caption or label can add clarification if needed.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh: CircuitLab made my IE10 go 'not responding'. I'll do it the other way you said though - use a couple of coils, and put a box around them.

Comment: When you say the relay is making noise it makes me think that something is oscillating. Why are you using an emitter follower to drive the relay, instead of an open collector? Why the resistor in parallel with the relay coil?

Comment: @jwygralak67: The idea was to drive a 3055 from the 2222, this attempt to drive the relay directly wasn't part of the plan.

Comment: A relay cannot show smooth, variable resistance over a 0 to 1 Kohm range; it cannot "open gradually"! It's just highly conductive contacts! What's happening is that it is opening and closing rapidly, toggling between "infinite" and near-zero resistance. The rate of this may be changing, which interacts with the smoothing/averaging behavior of the multimeter.  When you have rapid, time-varying behavior, what you need is an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustrated I eventually tried it all over again from scratch; and it worked!
In all probability it was a poor connection at some point.

Comment: I noticed this question got bumped recently because it doesn't have an accepted answer. You can accept your own answer if it's solved now so that doesn't keep happening and it doesn't appear unsolved.

Comment: @PeterJ Yes, it is resolved. (+: Thanks for the heads-up!